# connection for jpa failing in spring boot with multiple datasource after certain period of time

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, multiple-databases

I have configured multiple datasources in spring boot. it works well. but after certain period of time i am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection.close() has already been called. Invalid operation in this state.
```

here is my configuration

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = Array("application.yml"))
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  basePackages = Array("com.common.repository.company"),
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "companyEntityManager",
  transactionManagerRef = "companyTransactionManager"
)
class PersistenceCompanyConfiguration @Autowired()(env: Environment){

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.companyDataSource")
  def ipCompanyDataSource() : DataSource  = {
    DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
  }

  @Bean
  def companyEntityManager: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = {
    val em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    em.setDataSource(companyDataSource())
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.common.domain.company")
    val vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter)
    val properties: util.HashMap[String, Object] = new util.HashMap[String, Object]
    properties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto.auto"))
    properties.put("hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy", env.getProperty("hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy"))
    properties.put("hibernate.naming.physical-strategy  ", env.getProperty("hibernate.naming.physical-strategy"))
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"))
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties)
    em
  }

  @Bean
  def companyTransactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager = {
    val transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(companyEntityManager.getObject)
    transactionManager
  }
}
```

yaml configuration:

```
companyDataSource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://url:3306/call
    username: test
    password: test
  companyDataSource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://url:3306/call
    username: test
    password: test
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

ERROR:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection.close() has already been called. Invalid operation in this state.
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying few solution for 2 days, i found that giving above data-source configuration is not sufficient.

```
ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=null; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=false; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/leadboxer; username=root; validationQuery=null; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; useStatementFacade=true;
```

there are two additional properties which i have to set which reset a connection if it gets dropped from pull and test query before making actual query in spring boot.

```
companyDataSource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://url:3306/call
    username: test
    password: test
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
    testOnBorrow: true
  companyDataSource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://url:3306/call
    username: test
    password: test
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
    testOnBorrow: true
```

After adding following properties it was fixed my issue..

```
  validationQuery: SELECT 1
  testOnBorrow: true
```